# Am i missing any import?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter

While running

```
>   spark-submit   --class "TwitterPopularTags"   --master local[2]      >/home/raja/begin/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar

>  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                      >org/apache/spark/Logging
>...
>Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
>...
>"
```

My sbt is fine: clean, reload,compile, package but when I ran the above spark-submit, I got the above world famous error.

```
>My simple.sbt:

>    name := "Simple Project"
>    version := "1.0"
>    scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

>libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1",
>  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.1",
>  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.2",
>  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.7",
>  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4",
>  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.4",
>"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.7"
>)

>resolvers += "Maven Central" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
>resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

My imports:

```
>import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
>import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
>import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
>import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
>import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

>import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
>import org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>import org.apache.log4j.{Level, LogManager, PropertyConfigurator}
>import org.apache.log4j.Logger
>import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization
>import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
>import twitter4j.Twitter
>import twitter4j.Status
>import twitter4j.auth.Authorization
>import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
```

Please dont tell me to change version. I configured log4j.properties, properties but no chance. Is it SLF4J or Logback I have to look at? I tried to get spark-core jar for that version from maven but no chance.

Anyone can pin point me here

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: Is there are a "slf4j-api" dependency or something like that? I recall needing something else like that for a project of my own. In java I needed slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar(version may vary )

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect dependencies:

- Spark 2.0
- Spark Twitter connector 1.6

Twitter connector has been removed in Spark 2.0. You can use [Apache Bahir](https://bahir.apache.org/) or downgrade Spark to 1.6.

Comment: I have modified the code and recompiled with these details ,same error:                              libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.0",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.4",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.7" . I also changed to "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.1.0-SNAPSHOT" but no chance, same error. Is it SLF4J detail or log4j?